# Excel - Truncating a pasted formula with multiple decimal places to two decimal places

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

We need to change a formula result that was pasted into a cell to a number with 2 decimal places. For example, formula number that was pasted was 3817.984138.  We want it to paste as 3817.98. Can this be done?

Comment: What do you mean pasted? What formula are you using?

Comment: The formulas are basic sum or multiplication formulas.  So when we reference the cell with the formula or try to paste it to another cell, we get the full number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the format of the cell the formula is in to include only 2 decimal places? What about the target cells where you bring it to?

The roughest way to do this would be to format the function -

```
E1 = 1
E2 = 3
E3 = E1/E2 = 0.333333
E4 = TEXT(E1/E2,"0.00") = 0.33
```